# login page wont log in

Tags: php, authentication

I am getting a problem where my login details wont let me log into my page :(

so my set up page is

```
    <?php

  $db = mysql_connect("$host", "$dblogin", "$dbpassword");
  mysql_select_db("$dbname");

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdb WHERE email='$email'");
$playerinfo = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$date2 = date("H:i");   

function error($type)
{
    if($type == "field")
    {
echo '<body link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000000" text="#FFFFFF">';
        echo '<p align=center><font color="red">You have left fields blank. Please <a href="index.php">relogin</a></font></center></p>';
    }

    elseif($type == "password")
    {
      echo '<p><center><font color="red">Incorrect password. Please <a href="index.php">relogin</a></font></center></p>';
    }
}
echo '</body>';
?>
```

my login page is

```
    <body link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000000" text="#FFFFFF">

<p align="center">
<img border="0" src=logo.jpg></img></p>
<p align="center">
<form action=check.php method=post>
<p align="center"><font size=1><b><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Login.</font></b><br><br>
<samp style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 7pt; font-family: tahoma"><font face="Tahoma" size="2"><b>Email -</fomt></b></font></samp><font face="Tahoma" size="2"><b>
<input type="text" name="email" size="20" style="border: 1px solid black">
</b></font></font><font face="Tahoma" size="2">
<br>
<samp style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 7pt; font-family: tahoma">
<b><font face="Tahoma" size="2">Pass -</font></b></samp><b><font size="1" face="Tahoma"><input type="password" name="password" size="20" style="border: 1px solid black"></font></b><br><input type="submit" value="Log In" style="border: 1px solid black">
<br>
</form>
</body>
```

and my check.php page is

```
<?
session_start();
include("setup.php");

if(!$email || !$password) {

error("field");

exit();
}

if($password == $info['password']) {

session_register("password");
session_register("email");

include("top.php");

echo "<p><b><center>Welcome</center></b></p>";

echo "<p><u><b>Members Area</b></u></p>";

echo "<p><center>- <b><a href=>Page</a></b> -</center></p>";

echo "<p><center>- <b><a href=logout.php>Log Out</a></b> -</center></p>";

include("bottom.php");

}
else
{
    error("password");
}
?>
```

I always get a error of You have left fields blank. Please relogin from my index page so I cannot get my user to log in

where have I failed?

Comment: [Upgrade from the mysql extension](http://www.oleaass.com/why-people-needs-to-stop-using-the-mysql-extension/)

Comment: I am having trouble following what your code is actually doing, half your variables just appear out of nowhere so I have no idea what they are supposed to contain and the other half are being assigned to stuff but we never see how they get used.  You cut too much off of your code snippets I think

Comment: @lonelyranger .. i think you forgot to set your variables... check my answer below .. maybe it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not even set your variables :D That is why it is saying "You have left fields blank"

```
session_start();
include("setup.php");
```

After this include

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

Besides this : Use prepared statements to avoid [**SQL Injection**](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: that's the jam I was looking for, only problem now is it keeps saying incorrect password lol

Comment: That is because you are calling it `error("field");` with a string .. and then comparing it with whatever was typed in `$password` !! lol .. feel free to upvote this and accept the answer if it solved the original problem you posted @LonelyRanger :)

Comment: 1 of 2 you did that i asked  @LonelyRanger :P lol... anyways let me know if you get stuck again .. but try to use prepared statements ... or it can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be this:

```
   $db = mysql_connect("$host", "$dblogin", "$dbpassword");
```

I think you meant:

```
   $db = mysql_connect("{$host}", "{$dblogin}", "{$dbpassword}");
```

You cannot include variables into a string without the {}.

But even in that case, you need to define those varaibles before this line.

```
     $host = "ipaddress";
```

Also, once you get beyond that, you are treating strings as booleans:

```
     if(!$email || !$password)
```

Comment: sorry in those $host spots are replaced with the actual host address, databaselogin name, databasepassword. It is getting the information required as that process I used on my main page in order to retrieve data from my database in order to show up on my site.

Comment: what about in email='$email'?  and you my edit, you are treating strings as booleans.  !$email means email does not equal 1, right? you meant something more like $email!=''